# Method in sequence Diagram

Tags: class, uml, sequence-diagram

I have an Interview question, then I try to find It's question in Internet, but I cant find it.
[image]

I answered it, but I still confused with my answer. Because I think `Post()` is part of `Invoice` class too.

Comment: last choice, each operation is part (or inherited) by the target of the message if it is a call (not a response) so on the side of the arrow head

Comment: This test is flawed: there is no `Invoice` class, only an `Invoice` object. A class would be noted `:Invoice`.  Moreover the return message arrow should be open-headed and not plain-headed.  Finally, the use of an actor classifier is questionnable, since an interaction (sequence) show lifelines in principle within an enclosing classifier: an actor is by definition external to the system.  A gate end should have been used instead. Ok, I'm pinpointing at some details, but a test about UML knowledge should show exemplary UML knowledge and accuracy.

Comment: To amend Christophe's annotation: The term `method` is commonly used (mostly in the MS world) but what it should read here is `operation` (UML 2.5 p. 15: _operation owned by a class may have a related_ method _that defines its detailed behavior_)

Answer (score 3):

No. The message shows what *is called* not who/what *is calling*. So `Publish()` is an operation of `Invoice` and `Post()` is one of `GeneralLedger` (called from `Invoice`). `Validate()` is also an operation of `Invoice`. It's just a self-call here.

---

N.B. I'm using a colloquial description above. To start with, I repeat [@Christope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe)'s comment that the question itself is flawed.

- `method` is the wrong term. It is commonly used (mostly in the MS world) but what it should read here is operation (UML 2.5 p. 15: *operation owned by a class may have a related* method *that defines its detailed behavior*)
- Top of the life lines it only denotes objects, not the classes they were derived from. One could think of the class names being the same, but to be correct it needs to be `:<class>` or `<objName>:<class>`. Without colon it's only the object name.
- The return arrow has a wrong arrow. It needs to be an open one, not a filled one. Semantics of arrow renderings are crucial in UML.
- The messages (the solid lines ones above) are define in UML 2.5 (p.574) as *A message is shown as a line from the sender MessageEnd to the receiver MessageEnd. The line must be such that every line fragment is either horizontal or downwards when traversed from send event to receive event. The send and receive events may both be on the same lifeline. The form of the line or arrowhead reflects properties of the message...*
- So the text above the messages is the message signature which corresponds to an operation in the object pointed at (for more see the UML specs).

Comment: out of the fact I do not understand why you speak about `who/what is calling` because there is nothing in the OP question about that, you are wrong to say `not who/what is calling` because the class *Message* has the association end *sendEvent* which references the sending of the message (its type is *MessageEnd* being an abstract class implemented by *MessageOccurrenceSpecification* inheriting *OccurrenceSpecification* having the association end *covered* of type *LifeLine*) in the same way it also has the association end *receiveEvent* which references the receiving of the message

Comment: @bruno I understand "call" to colloquially refer to the invocation of an operation, in view of p.572:  "The signature of a Message refers to either an Operation or a Signal. The name of the Message must be the same as the name of the referenced Operation or Signal".

Comment: @Christophe the signature of a message is one of its association ends, not the message int its all, and in his answer qwerty_so says `the message ...` not `the signature of the message ...`